# How to allow users to reset passwords in Time Capsule accounts?

Tags: macos, time-machine, time-capsule, accounts

I have a Time Capsule that I share with others in the office. I control the base station and create accounts for others to backup their machines with Time Machine i.e., using

```
Airport Utility > Time Capsule > Disks> Secure Shared Disks — with accounts
```

I create accounts and a password for them (or they're free to enter it on my machine), but I also keep getting requests for password resets or changing passwords, which makes it a pain — people need to come to my machine to do it.

Is there a way to allow users to change their passwords whenever they choose from the convenience of their machine?

I'm using the Time Capsule with Mountain Lion (as are most others, and some with Lion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - this is a big admin bottleneck if you aren't going to set up a machine to re-share the disk or just share files and back up to the disk so you can have more of a server based permissions and account management toolset.

Comment: "server based permissions and account management toolset" could you elaborate on that? I understood the shared disk setup to mean that everyone could access others' files unless it was encrypted. Is this not the case?

Comment: Oh - if you use OS X Server - you can use the profile manager, workgroup manager, LDAP, Active Directory - those are the tools to which I am referring. Airport doesn't really have tools it wants to follow to allow you to offload the need to reset passwords one by one on the base station for the file sharing accounts.

Comment: Ah, ok. It's not OS X Server... we're all on our individual macs.

Comment: Yes - for cases like yours, I end up setting up sharing on a local Mac with a USB connected drive and then backing that Mac/drive up to the Time Capsule - people can go in and read the latest backup (if needed), but to write to things or access it directly, they use the account on the mac. I set them each up an account and they can manage to change their passwords as needed and since Lion, the second user can log in on a virtual screen and not mess with the main user of the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is long-resolved, but you can use the Time Capsule setting "Secure Shared Disks - With Disk Password" instead of using Accounts." And Mike is right about Mac OS X Server and Access Control Levels for Users. Just remember, Passwords for anything should be changed on a regular basis.