# Time Capsule user account password change

Tags: time-machine, password, airport, time-capsule, user-account

I installed a Time Capsule at my office to handle backups of all Macbooks (8).

To ensure a minimum of privacy, via **Airport Utility-->Disks** I created One account per each user (Changed S**ecured Shared Disks-->With accounts**).

I used a default password so each user would then sign in via Finder and then change it to something else.

I've been trying to figure out how a regular user with no access to the Time Capsule main password would go in and update his own password.

When I connect from finder to the Time Capsule a modal comes in to sign in and there's a button to change password.

[image: Sign in dialog]

Clicking on change password triggers a new modal to input old password, new password and verify.
After I click Change Password I always get an error like this:

[image]

If I sign in with my assigned password, I can access to my Shared disk account without problems so it cannot be an invalid IP or server name because I can access, I just can't change the password.

**How do you change a user password on a user account within Time Capsule without using Airport Utility when you know your current user account user & password but you don't know the device password of the Time Capsule.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a recurring problem with TC devices. I have managed to setup users on a TC in the past, but never had others attempted to change the password. That may be a limitation to the user who created the accounts/setup the TC. Are they able to create their own accounts from their machines? If so, that may help you with the issue.

In closing, I know most people get the TC with the hope of being able to backup and use it as a NAS, but there are a lot of limitations with it. Right now, there are a lot of other solutions that can accomplish Time Machine backups, and act as a full-fledged NAS. I am currently running such setup on a Netgear Nighthawk, and I love being able to backup my Mac AND Windows machines.

Further efforts: Start by digging Through [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59128/how-to-allow-users-to-reset-passwords-in-time-capsule-accounts). My second suggestion is to post directly in the [Time Capsule Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/community/wireless/time_capsule). You may want to follow [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7649884) as well (unless it was posted by you :P)